# Module / Driver "rtl8723bs" on Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: 17.04

How to have the wifi driver "rtl8723bs" on Ubuntu 17.04?

I've tried the make; make install process for https://github.com/hadess/rtl8723bs

I am thinking that somethings missing. Somehow no modules are produced.

It could be something more like this branch is needed: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/staging/rtl8723bs

Comment: Ubuntu kernels 4.3 and newer require signed modules if secure boot is on. Turn off secure boot.

Comment: 17.04 uses kernel 4.10 - which doesn't have the module in its tree. So It'd be nice if there is a way to bring it to that kernel. A quick search in Ubuntu Artful (17.10) files does find it. However I'd like the Long Term Support of 17.04.

Comment: 17.04 is not LTS, so you won't get Long Term Support.

Comment: Ah, so it would seem you are right.